# JavaScript Fo.FolderExist() wont work in a PHP echo but does return true in HTML

Tags: javascript, php

```
if (path.value.length>0 && Fo.FolderExists(path.value)){
    echo "alert(path.value.lenght);"; // works
    echo "alert(Fo.FolderExists(path.value));" // fails
}
```

although `alert(Fo.FolderExists(path.value));` works.

any reason why it fails when echoed in PHP?

Comment: Because echo is a PHP language construct, and from what I understand, you are in a JavaScript environment. This would work in a php file: `<?php echo "alert(Fo.FolderExists(path.value));" ?>`

Comment: Is this code snippet suppose to be php or JS? if JS then you cannot use `echo`, if php then `.` dot is not a **object reference** but **string concatenation operator** and `path.value.length>0` means you are joining three constants then comparing to 0

Comment: @ Marcel - no Its a .PHP file THat java is a snipet of the code where it all of it is placed in a PHP echo ' ';

Comment: I'm not even sure how you're getting `echo "alert(path.value.lenght);";` to work, but you're getting confused about where php ends and javascript begins. Go back to basics and read some tutorials.

Comment: @ Ivan - Yes its a small snipet of the code...  The path.value is of the drive you want to search and it has to be 3 characters long i.e. "C:\" and it works as there are two fields 'Search for' & 'Search Drive'

Comment: @ CodeMoose - it all works, just not that Fo.FolderExits(path.value) and the 'if' is where the code fails.  Your not being helpful one bit... I take it your read the tutorials...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript runs on a user's computer, PHP runs on your server. There is absolutely zero shared programming going on there. IF you want to see what PHP generated, generate it, and echo that:

```
if (path.value.length>0 && Fo.FolderExists(path.value)){
  echo "alert(path.value.lenght);";
  echo "alert('" . Fo.FolderExists(path.value) . "');" // will work
}
```

or even more explicitly:

```
if (path.value.length>0 && Fo.FolderExists(path.value)){
  echo "alert(path.value.lenght);";
  $path_value = Fo.FolderExists(path.value);
  echo "alert('$path_value');" // will work
}
```